# button to copy inner html to another element works but with a bug

Tags: javascript, html, css

Click counter unit-total is being displayed in a span with id corresponding to the current day of the week when save total button is clicked. If the total is zero the text is placed lower than it should. Page is here: http://unitcounter.infinityfreeapp.com/
[image: screenshot of issue]
I would like this to not happen. I tried

```
const weekday = ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"];
const d = new Date();
let day = weekday[d.getDay()];
let id = day;
document.getElementById("button-save").addEventListener("click", function () {
  const total = Number(document.getElementById("total-units").innerHTML);
  if (total > 0) {
 document.getElementById(id).innerText = document.getElementById("total-units").innerHTML;}
  
  else {
    document.getElementById(id).innerText = 0;
  }
});
```

the code runs but does not fix my problem. Below is my full code

```
<body>
    <div class="block-wrapper">
        <div class="tile">
            <div class="c-block" data-config-click='{"selectors":{"trigger":".button","target": ".result","reset":".button-reset", "weight": 9, "resultElement": "#total-units"}}'>
                <b class="result"></b>
                <button class="button button-primary" type="button">
                    Document Count
                </button>
                <button class=" button button-reset">
                    Reset
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tile">
            <div class="c-block" data-config-click='{"selectors":{"trigger":".button","target": ".result","reset":".button-reset", "weight": 1, "resultElement": "#total-units"}}'>
                <b class="result"></b>
                <button class="button button-secondary" type="button">
                    Verified Videos
                </button>
                <button class="button button-reset">
                    Reset
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tile">
            <div class="c-block">
                <div id="app">
                </div>
                <button class="button buttontimer button-start" type="button">
                    Start Timer
                </button>
        <form name="customForm" id="custom">
        <input type="text" id="minutes" placeholder="Enter Minutes" autocomplete="off">
      </form>
                <button class=" button buttontimer button-start-reset" type="button">
                    Reset
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="./script.js"></script>
    <span class="totaltile">
        <p>Total Units =&nbsp;
            <span id="total-units">
                0
            </span>
      <button id="button-save">
                    Save Total
                </button>
        </p>
    </span>
  <span class="weekTile">
  <div class="weeklyTotals">
  Weekly Totals
  </div>
<div class="weekdays">
  <span id="sun">
    <p>S</p>
    <span id="Sunday"> 0 </span>
  </span>
    <span id="mon">
      <p>M</p>
      <span id="Monday">0 </span>
  </span>
  <span id="tues">
    <p>T</p>
      <span id="Tuesday">0 </span>
  </span>
  <span id="wed">
    <p>W</p>
      <span id="Wednesday">0 </span>
  </span>
  <span id="thur">
    <p>T</p>
     <span id="Thursday">0 </span>
  </span>
  <span id="fri">
    <p>F</p>
      <span id="Friday">0 </span>
  </span>
  <span id="sat">
    <p>S</p>
    <span id="Saturday">0 </span>
  </span>
  </div>
</body>

body {
    background: #000000;
    height: 100vh;
    font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Oxygen,
        Ubuntu, Cantarell, "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
}

.block-wrapper {
    width: 100vw;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: auto;
}

.c-block {
    margin: 30px;
}

button,
b {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}

button {
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

button:focus {
    outline: none;
}

.tile {
    background-color: #000000;
    margin-top: 40px;
    width: 375px;
    height: 425px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    border: solid;
    border-color: rgb(170, 170, 170, 0.5);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 20px;
}

.button {
    margin-top: 40px;
    color: rgb(0, 190, 255);
    padding: 4px 10px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    border: solid;
    border-color: rgb(170, 170, 170, 0.5);
    font-size: 32px;
}

.buttontimer {
    margin-top: 40px;
    color: rgb(0, 190, 255);
    padding: 4px 10px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    border: solid;
    border-color: rgb(170, 170, 170, 0.5);
    font-size: 32px;
}

input {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  background-color: rgb(85, 85, 85, 0.4);
    color: rgb(0, 190, 255);
    padding: 5px 5px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    border: solid;
    border-color: rgb(170, 170, 170, 0.5);
    color: rgb(0, 190, 255);
  font-size: 16px;
  outline: none;
}

.button:hover {
    opacity: 0.9;
}

.button[disabled] {
    opacity: 0.7;
    cursor: not-allowed;
}

.button-primary {
    background-color: rgb(85, 85, 85, 0.4);
}

.button-secondary {
    background-color: rgb(85, 85, 85, 0.4);
}

.button-reset {
    background-color: rgb(85, 85, 85, 0.4);
    color: rgb(0, 190, 255);
    margin: 12px auto 0;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 4px 56px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    border: solid;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-color: rgb(170, 170, 170, 0.5);
}

#app {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: auto;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.button-start {
    background-color: rgb(85, 85, 85, 0.4);
    color: rgb(0, 190, 255);
    margin: 12px auto 0;
    padding: 4px 10px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    border: solid;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-color: rgb(170, 170, 170, 0.5);
}

.button-start-reset {
    background-color: rgb(85, 85, 85, 0.4);
    color: rgb(0, 190, 255);
    margin: 12px auto 0;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 4px 56px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    border: solid;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-color: rgb(170, 170, 170, 0.5);
}

.result {
    color: rgb(0, 190, 255);
    font-size: 100px;
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 90px;
}

.totaltile {
    width: 500px;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 4px 10px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    border: solid;
    border-color: rgb(170, 170, 170, 0.5);
    font-size: 32px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: auto;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#button-save {
    background-color: rgb(85, 85, 85, 0.4);
    color: rgb(0, 190, 255);
    margin: 5px 0;
  margin-left: 50px;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 4px 26px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    border: solid;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-color: rgb(170, 170, 170, 0.5);
}

p {
  display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: auto;
    color: rgb(0, 190, 255);
    font-size: 32px;
}

.base-timer {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}

.base-timer__svg {
    transform: scaleX(-1);
}

.base-timer__circle {
    fill: none;
    stroke: none;
}

.base-timer__path-elapsed {
    stroke-width: 7px;
    stroke: grey;
}

.base-timer__path-remaining {
    stroke-width: 7px;
    stroke-linecap: round;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform-origin: center;
    transition: 1s linear all;
    fill-rule: nonzero;
    stroke: currentColor;
}

.base-timer__path-remaining.green {
    color: rgb(65, 184, 131);
}

.base-timer__path-remaining.orange {
    color: orange;
}

.base-timer__path-remaining.red {
    color: red;
}

.base-timer__label {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    top: 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    font-size: 45px;
    color: rgb(0, 190, 255);
}

.timerpadding {
    margin-top: 50px;
}

::placeholder {
  color: rgb(0, 190, 255);
  text-align: center;
}

.weekdays {
    width: 500px;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 4px 10px;
    font-size: 32px;
  color: rgb(0, 190, 255);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: auto;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  
}

.weeklyTotals {
    color: rgb(0, 190, 255);
  font-size: 16px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

#sun, #mon, #tues, #wed, #thur, #fri, #sat{
  width: 40px;
  height: 80px;
    padding: 4px 10px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    border: solid;
    border-color: rgb(170, 170, 170, 0.5);
}

#Sunday, #Monday, #Tuesday, #Wednesday, #Thursday, #Friday, #Saturday {
  width: 40px;
  height: 80px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: auto;
}

window.onload = () => {
    class ClickCount {
        constructor(obj) {
            this.triggerNode = obj.triggerNode;
            this.targetNode = obj.targetNode;
            this.resetNode = obj.resetNode;
            this.weight = obj.weight;
            this.resultNode = obj.resultNode;
            this.count = 0;
            this.handleClick();
            this.handleCount();
        }

        increaseTotal() {
            let currentTotal = isNaN(this.resultNode.innerHTML)
                ? 0
                : parseInt(this.resultNode.innerHTML);
            const weightedCount = parseInt(this.count / this.weight);
            currentTotal -= weightedCount;
            const increasedWeightedCount = parseInt((this.count + 1) / this.weight);
            currentTotal += increasedWeightedCount;

            this.resultNode.innerHTML = currentTotal;
        }

        decreaseTotal() {
            let currentTotal = isNaN(this.resultNode.innerHTML)
                ? 0
                : parseInt(this.resultNode.innerHTML);
            const weightedCount = parseInt(this.count / this.weight);
            currentTotal -= weightedCount;

            this.resultNode.innerHTML = currentTotal;
        }

        handleClick() {
            this.triggerNode.addEventListener("click", () => {
                this.increaseTotal();
                this.handleCount({
                    count: this.count++
                });
            });
            this.resetNode.addEventListener("click", () => this.handleReset());
        }

        handleCount() {
            this.targetNode.innerHTML = this.count;
        }

        handleReset() {
            this.decreaseTotal();
            this.count = 0;
            this.handleCount();
        }
    }

    const clickBlock = document.querySelectorAll("[data-config-click]");

    clickBlock.forEach((block) => {
        const config = JSON.parse(block.dataset.configClick);
        const { trigger, target, reset, weight, resultElement } = config.selectors;
        const triggerNode = block.querySelector(trigger);
        const targetNode = block.querySelector(target);
        const resetNode = block.querySelector(reset);
        const resultNode = document.querySelector(resultElement);

        if (triggerNode && targetNode) {
            new ClickCount({
                triggerNode,
                targetNode,
                resetNode,
                resultNode,
                weight
            });     
        }
    });

}


const FULL_DASH_ARRAY = 283;
const WARNING_THRESHOLD = 10;
const ALERT_THRESHOLD = 5;

const COLOR_CODES = {
    info: {
        color: "green"
    },
    warning: {
        color: "orange",
        threshold: WARNING_THRESHOLD
    },
    alert: {
        color: "red",
        threshold: ALERT_THRESHOLD
    }
}
let minutes = 120;
let TIME_LIMIT = minutes;
let timePassed = 0;
let timeLeft = TIME_LIMIT;
let timerInterval = null;
let remainingPathColor = COLOR_CODES.info.color;
let isRunning = false;

document.getElementById("app").innerHTML = `
<div class="base-timer">
  <svg class="base-timer__svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <g class="base-timer__circle">
      <circle class="base-timer__path-elapsed" cx="50" cy="50" r="45"></circle>
      <path
        id="base-timer-path-remaining"
        stroke-dasharray="283"
        class="base-timer__path-remaining ${remainingPathColor}"
        d="
          M 50, 50
          m -45, 0
          a 45,45 0 1,0 90,0
          a 45,45 0 1,0 -90,0
        "
      ></path>
    </g>
  </svg>
  <span id="base-timer-label" class="base-timer__label">${formatTime(
            timeLeft
        )}</span>
</div>
`;
//Start timer button
document.querySelector(".button-start").addEventListener("click", function () {
    if (isRunning) return;
    isRunning = true;   
  startTimer();
});
//Enter custom countdown time 
document.customForm.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  onTimesUp();
  let minutes = document.getElementById("minutes").value;
  const mins = this.minutes.value;
  TIME_LIMIT = mins * 60;
document.getElementById('minutes').value=null;
  startTimer();
});
//Reset button
document
    .querySelector(".button-start-reset")
    .addEventListener("click", function () {
        onTimesUp();
        resetTimer();
    });
//Reset timer
function resetTimer() {
    isRunning = false;
    const { alert, warning, info } = COLOR_CODES;
    timeLeft = TIME_LIMIT=120;
    document.getElementById("base-timer-label").innerHTML = formatTime(timeLeft);
    setCircleDasharray();
    document
        .getElementById("base-timer-path-remaining")
        .classList.remove(warning.color);
    document
        .getElementById("base-timer-path-remaining")
        .classList.remove(alert.color);
    document.getElementById("base-timer-path-remaining").classList.add(info.color);
}
//Times up
function onTimesUp() {
    clearInterval(timerInterval);
}
//Start timer
function startTimer() {
    timePassed = 0;
    timerInterval = setInterval(() => {
        timePassed = timePassed += 1;
        timeLeft = TIME_LIMIT - timePassed;
        document.getElementById("base-timer-label").innerHTML = formatTime(timeLeft);
        setCircleDasharray();
        setRemainingPathColor(timeLeft);

        if (timeLeft === 0) {
            onTimesUp();
            resetTimer();
        }
    }, 1000);
}

function formatTime(time) {
    const minutes = Math.floor(time / 60);
    let seconds = time % 60;

    if (seconds < 10) {
        seconds = `0${seconds}`;
    }

    return `${minutes}:${seconds}`;
}

function setRemainingPathColor(timeLeft) {
    const { alert, warning, info } = COLOR_CODES;
    if (timeLeft <= alert.threshold) {
        document
            .getElementById("base-timer-path-remaining")
            .classList.remove(warning.color);
        document
            .getElementById("base-timer-path-remaining")
            .classList.add(alert.color);
    } else if (timeLeft <= warning.threshold) {
        document
            .getElementById("base-timer-path-remaining")
            .classList.remove(info.color);
        document
            .getElementById("base-timer-path-remaining")
            .classList.add(warning.color);
    }
}

function calculateTimeFraction() {
    const rawTimeFraction = timeLeft / TIME_LIMIT;
    return rawTimeFraction - (1 / TIME_LIMIT) * (1 - rawTimeFraction);
}

function setCircleDasharray() {
    const circleDasharray = `${(calculateTimeFraction() * FULL_DASH_ARRAY).toFixed(
        0
    )} 283`;
    document
        .getElementById("base-timer-path-remaining")
        .setAttribute("stroke-dasharray", circleDasharray);
}
 const weekday = ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"];
const d = new Date();
let day = weekday[d.getDay()];
let id = day;
document.getElementById("button-save").addEventListener("click", function () {
  const total = Number(document.getElementById("total-units").innerHTML);
  if (total > 0) {
 document.getElementById(id).innerText = document.getElementById("total-units").innerHTML;}
  
  else {
    document.getElementById(id).innerText = 0;
  }
});
```

If I click the save button the text should be placed over top of the existing text not farther down. Where is my error?

Comment: Your code work, just put script at the bottom of page.

Comment: The text gets placed lower than it should when the total is zero.  Try it http://unitcounter.infinityfreeapp.com/ the text is fine if the total is greater than 0

Comment: I added a screenshot for reference. I put the script at the bottom but that didn't work.

Comment: With chrome the zero is perfectly align.. which browser do you use?

Comment: i'm using chrome. When I click the button Save Total and unit-total is zero the zero aligns like the screenshot I uploaded. If the total is any number above that it aligns correctly.

Comment: Not so from me, please clear cache 99% is that.